# Creating an SQLDatabase using schema file instead of URI

Tags: python, langchain, py-langchain

Currently experimenting with the SQLDatabaseChain were the end result would be to generate the SQL statesmen, not running the query

Is there a way to create SQLDatabase from schema file,  hence avoiding giving the SQLDatabase  actual connection to the database?

Is it possible to not use the SQLDatabaseChain at all, and provide the schema to MML for processing in another way?

BR

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I provide a detail DB overview for Chatbot ( I use the ConversationalRetrivalChain for this case) and it return the context, the SQL query base on Overview DB. It's very good on my case. You can try it. Hope it useful for you.